# Get text from PDF in Google

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, drive

I have a PDF document that is saved in Google Drive. I can use the Google Drive Web UI search to find text in the document.

How can I programmatically extract a portion of the text in the document using Google Apps Script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23771146/google-drive-php-api-how-to-stream-a-large-file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See `pdfToText()` in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/e6795e438615d252584f).

To invoke the OCR built in to Google Drive on a PDF file, e.g. `myPDF.pdf`, here is what you do:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var pdfFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName("myPDF.pdf").next();
  var blob = pdfFile.getBlob();

  // Get the text from pdf
  var filetext = pdfToText( blob, {keepTextfile: false} );

  // Now do whatever you want with filetext...
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to extract PDF annotations with highlighted texts?