# GAS error: "invalid argument (line 3, "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script

This is the code:

```
    function dataAutofill() {
    var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl('inserted drive link here');
    console.log(doc);
    }
```

> GAS error: "invalid argument (line 3, "Code")

I intend to read a drive link that opens a PDF view, extract the information from it and then write that information into a spreadsheet. However, I have gotten stuck at the point where the function reads the data..

Edit 1: It is already been pointed out that i can't use `openbyURl` throught DocumentApp

Comment: Welcome. You've commented out "var url = ", so what did you use for 'inserted drive link here'?

Comment: I tried putting the link through "var url = " as well as placing the link directly between the quotes.. separate times of course

Comment: @AdityaKumar - what kind of document are you trying to open? Spreadsheets (Sheets), Presentation (Slides), Word docs (Docs) , pdf, csv, txt or something else?

Comment: @AdityaKumar Just want to confirm that this document IS not the bound document - it is another document on your Google Drive, AND/OR you have permission to access the file.

Comment: its a drive link that opens a pdf, i have permission to open it. it is not bound to the active sheet

Comment: You can't use DocumentApp to open a PDF as it is meant to work with Docs. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks Jescanellas. I want to read PDF documents for information and write that data into a spreadsheet

Comment: @AdityaKumar - it would help if you could perhaps update your question. Kindly try and be a little more specific in what's required and what you've tried so far :) This would avoid us from discussing major changes over comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get text from PDF in Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166664/get-text-from-pdf-in-google)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to import the contents of a PDF file  (as text) into a Google Spreadsheet.

As indicated by @Jescanellas, this is covered by the topic [Get text from PDF in Google](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38188277/1330560). Mogsdad's answer is particularly useful, and the following answer does nothing more than string together the various components into a single answer relevant to your scenario.

As a proof of concept - I created a simple table using Google Document, saved the document to a PDF file, loaded the PDF file into a Google Drive folder, then ran this script (which is bound to a spreadsheet). The PDF file is inserted into cell "A1" of the spreadsheet. This approach does not pretend to reflect your data - for which, one imagines, you will have a method to populate the cells of the spreadsheet.

**Resources> Advanced Google services - Drive API**

The script requires that the Drive API should be enabled under the Script editor:
  Resources > Advanced Google services > Drive API.

**Note:**

[Mogsdad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38188277/1330560) refers to a function `pdfToText()` to be found as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/e6795e438615d252584f) (pdfToText.js). Future readers of this answer should note this since the gist may change over time.

---

```
function so5838796101() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "58387961";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  // identify the PDF file
  var pdfFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName("so_58387961_export_from_Google_Docs.pdf").next();
  var blob = pdfFile.getBlob();

  // Get the text from pdf
    // this uses Mogsdad's gist
  var filetext = pdfToText( blob, {keepTextfile: false} );

  // define destination and set value
  var sheetdata =sheet.getRange("A1");
  sheetdata.setValue(filetext);
}

// Mogsdad's gist start
/**
 * Convert pdf file (blob) to a text file on Drive, using built-in OCR.
 * By default, the text file will be placed in the root folder, with the same
 * name as source pdf (but extension 'txt'). Options:
 *   keepPdf (boolean, default false)     Keep a copy of the original PDF file.
 *   keepGdoc (boolean, default false)    Keep a copy of the OCR Google Doc file.
 *   keepTextfile (boolean, default true) Keep a copy of the text file.
 *   path (string, default blank)         Folder path to store file(s) in.
 *   ocrLanguage (ISO 639-1 code)         Default 'en'.
 *   textResult (boolean, default false)  If true and keepTextfile true, return
 *                                        string of text content. If keepTextfile
 *                                        is false, text content is returned without
 *                                        regard to this option. Otherwise, return
 *                                        id of textfile.
 *
 * @param {blob}   pdfFile    Blob containing pdf file
 * @param {object} options    (Optional) Object specifying handling details
 *
 * @returns {string}          id of text file (default) or text content
 */
function pdfToText ( pdfFile, options ) {
  // Ensure Advanced Drive Service is enabled
  try {
    Drive.Files.list();
  }
  catch (e) {
    throw new Error( "To use pdfToText(), first enable 'Drive API' in Resources > Advanced Google Services." );
  }

  // Set default options
  options = options || {};
  options.keepTextfile = options.hasOwnProperty("keepTextfile") ? options.keepTextfile : true;

  // Prepare resource object for file creation
  var parents = [];
  if (options.path) {
    parents.push( getDriveFolderFromPath (options.path) );
  }
  var pdfName = pdfFile.getName();
  var resource = {
    title: pdfName,
    mimeType: pdfFile.getContentType(),
    parents: parents
  };

  // Save PDF to Drive, if requested
  if (options.keepPdf) {
    var file = Drive.Files.insert(resource, pdfFile);
  }

  // Save PDF as GDOC
  resource.title = pdfName.replace(/pdf$/, 'gdoc');
  var insertOpts = {
    ocr: true,
    ocrLanguage: options.ocrLanguage || 'en'
  }
  var gdocFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, pdfFile, insertOpts);

  // Get text from GDOC  
  var gdocDoc = DocumentApp.openById(gdocFile.id);
  var text = gdocDoc.getBody().getText();

  // We're done using the Gdoc. Unless requested to keepGdoc, delete it.
  if (!options.keepGdoc) {
    Drive.Files.remove(gdocFile.id);
  }

  // Save text file, if requested
  if (options.keepTextfile) {
    resource.title = pdfName.replace(/pdf$/, 'txt');
    resource.mimeType = MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT;

    var textBlob = Utilities.newBlob(text, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT, resource.title);
    var textFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, textBlob);
  }

  // Return result of conversion
  if (!options.keepTextfile || options.textResult) {
    return text;
  }
  else {
    return textFile.id
  }
}

// Helper utility from http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gooscript/driveapppathfolder
function getDriveFolderFromPath (path) {
  return (path || "/").split("/").reduce ( function(prev,current) {
    if (prev && current) {
      var fldrs = prev.getFoldersByName(current);
      return fldrs.hasNext() ? fldrs.next() : null;
    }
    else { 
      return current ? null : prev; 
    }
  },DriveApp.getRootFolder()); 
}
// Mogsdad's gist end
```

Comment: thank you tedinoz! i had found the mogsdad post. however, his/her solution also didn't work on my end