# Google Script - Read PDF file, recognised as text/html

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, ocr

Do you have any idea how to read PDF files, which mimetype is text/html?

I have tried the snippet below, but OCR doesn't work, resulting in this issue *"API call to drive.files.insert failed with error: OCR is not supported for files of type text/html"*

```
function extractTextFromPDF(pdfID) {
      // PDF File URL
      // You can also pull PDFs from Google Drive
      var url =  "https://drive.google.com/file/d/"+pdfID
      var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
      var resource = {
        title: blob.getName(),
        mimeType: blob.getContentType(),
      };
    
      // Enable the Advanced Drive API Service
      var file = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob, { ocr: true, ocrLanguage: 'en' });
    
      // Extract Text from PDF file
      var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.id);
      var text = doc.getBody().getText();
    
      return text;
    }
```

Also, I have tried to convert files to any other format like .csv .css or text, but when did it the text is horrible, long HTML, with content encrypted I think. I considered splitting data from extracted HTML, but unfortunately, content is not there or is encrypted somehow.

What I want to do is to print the text from this wired pdf, so I can later write it to Google Sheets. Do you have any idea how I can read this file?
File
I am attaching a pdf here, so you can see what I am fighting with.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HXQk6PU9hzBb26EwoFQ0840W6ZihDUIX/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used your sample file, see how I did it below:

```
function myFunction() {
  var pdfFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName("222-1522118.pdf").next();
  var blob = pdfFile.getBlob();

  // Get the text from pdf
  var filetext = pdfToText( blob, {keepTextfile: false} );

  console.log(filetext)
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

I used Mogsdad's library [pdfToText](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mogsdad/e6795e438615d252584f/raw/b81891d3108e66059f56361c58f01590deff6746/pdfToText.js)

Reference: [Get text from PDF in Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38166664/get-text-from-pdf-in-google)

Comment: Sorry for commenting on old answer, Can you please help me to explain how did you load the "pdftotext" library to google app script?