# Gscript PDF to text by OCR, problem with some characters

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf, ocr, google-docs, pdftotext

I've been using the function attached below for over a year and it worked perfectly. However, 2 days ago, something changed and it stopped converting Polish characters in multiple installations.  I have tried the iso function based on ISO 639-1 code, and there is no difference.

Each time it runs, it skips polish letters. **Do you have any idea what can be changed to still read the Polish language?**

An example PDF file is available here to download: https://file.io/HOfUPv2oHZFK

```js
/**
 * Convert pdf file (blob) to a text file on Drive, using built-in OCR.
 * By default, the text file will be placed in the root folder, with the same
 * name as source pdf (but extension 'txt'). Options:
 *   keepPdf (boolean, default false)     Keep a copy of the original PDF file.
 *   keepGdoc (boolean, default false)    Keep a copy of the OCR Google Doc file.
 *   keepTextfile (boolean, default true) Keep a copy of the text file.
 *   path (string, default blank)         Folder path to store file(s) in.
 *   ocrLanguage (ISO 639-1 code)         Default 'en'.
 *   textResult (boolean, default false)  If true and keepTextfile true, return
 *                                        string of text content. If keepTextfile
 *                                        is false, text content is returned without
 *                                        regard to this option. Otherwise, return
 *                                        id of textfile.
 *
 * @param {blob}   pdfFile    Blob containing pdf file
 * @param {object} options    (Optional) Object specifying handling details
 *
 * @returns {string}          id of text file (default) or text content
 */
  function pdfToText ( pdfFile, options ) {
    // Ensure Advanced Drive Service is enabled
    try {
      Drive.Files.list();
    }
    catch (e) {
      throw new Error( "To use pdfToText(), first enable 'Drive API' in Resources > Advanced Google Services." );
    }

    // Set default options
    options = options || {};
    options.keepTextfile = options.hasOwnProperty("keepTextfile") ? options.keepTextfile : true;

    // Prepare resource object for file creation
    var parents = [];
    if (options.path) {
      parents.push( getDriveFolderFromPath (options.path) );
    }
    var pdfName = pdfFile.getName();
    var resource = {
      title: pdfName,
      mimeType: pdfFile.getContentType(),
      parents: parents
    };

    // Save PDF to Drive, if requested
    if (options.keepPdf) {
      var file = Drive.Files.insert(resource, pdfFile);
    }

    Logger.log(resource)

    // Save PDF as GDOC
    resource.title = pdfName.replace(/pdf$/, 'gdoc');
    var insertOpts = {
      ocr: true,
      ocrLanguage: options.ocrLanguage || 'pl'
    }
    var gdocFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, pdfFile, insertOpts);

    // Get text from GDOC  
    var gdocDoc = DocumentApp.openById(gdocFile.id);
    var text = gdocDoc.getBody().getText();

    Logger.log(text)

    // We're done using the Gdoc. Unless requested to keepGdoc, delete it.
    if (!options.keepGdoc) {
      Drive.Files.remove(gdocFile.id);
    }

    // Save text file, if requested
    if (options.keepTextfile) {
      resource.title = pdfName.replace(/pdf$/, 'txt');
      resource.mimeType = MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT;

      var textBlob = Utilities.newBlob(text, MimeType.PLAIN_TEXT, resource.title);
      var textFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, textBlob);
    }

    // Return result of conversion
    if (!options.keepTextfile || options.textResult) {
      return text;
    }
    else {
      return textFile.id
    }
  }

  // Helper utility from http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/gooscript/driveapppathfolder
  function getDriveFolderFromPath (path) {
    return (path || "/").split("/").reduce ( function(prev,current) {
      if (prev && current) {
        var fldrs = prev.getFoldersByName(current);
        return fldrs.hasNext() ? fldrs.next() : null;
      }
      else { 
        return current ? null : prev; 
      }
    },DriveApp.getRootFolder()); 
  }
```

Comment: I tried replicating using the provided code here on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71588237/google-script-read-pdf-file-recognised-as-text-html), and it is logging correctly using a sample file I created with random polish characters I could find all over the internet. Are there any errors or logs you can share?

Comment: Here attaching log from G-console (Just removed confidential parameters and last sentence

Comment: There is no error, it just upon conversion from pdf to Gdoc, skips Polish characters.  In your case, there is no such error? I tried on another Google account and the clean script had the same results. I tried to remove the possibility of some changes in account settings.

Comment: Can you share your sample file as well so that I can test from there?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.